Where can I buy Extra Large Kittel?
I am very tall and large (6'6" and 390lb). My current Kittel came stained, and I have been trying to replace it, but the largest size ones  I have been able to find (Keter 3xl) are all too small.
The one I have now is branded "Rimon Judaica Jerusalem LTD" and size XXL and fits well, but I have not been able to find any information about this brand or anyone who caries it.
Does anyone have any info about where to find this brand or similar sized Kittels?

This might sound a bit facetious, but maybe ask your local Chevra Kaddisha. A man is buried with a kittel, after all, and possibly they've had occasion to do a chessed shel emes with someone of your size (tibadel l'chayim tovim) and would know of suppliers for the purpose.

@Meir Tachrichim (burial shrouds) are white like a kittel but are not the same garment.
